# My activity indicator is not appearing

Tags: swift, activity-indicator

I want to show an activity indicator after the user enters login credentials and clicks the login button. This seemed straight forward but the indicator is not showing when I run (build succeeded). I am not sure if this is because when the app runs for real, it will be passing the credentials up to a server for verification but that code is not active yet, so the login is instantaneous, or if I have written this wrong but not to cause an error. Thank you for your help.

```
 @IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    //add error checking for loginEntered and passwordEntered if they are blank
    if loginEntered.text == "" || passwordEntered.text == "" {

        //Define the variable error for the message that should be displayed
        self.alertError = "Please enter your Login ID and/or Password"

    }

    if self.alertError != ""  { //if there is an error with the login

        //Display the error message on screen
        self.displayAlert("Missing Required Information", error: alertError)

        //reset error variable
        self.alertError = ""

        //return the user to the LoginID field and empty it if there is data in it. Empty the password field too.  ?? How do I do that??

    } else { //the login ID and password are entered

        //setup for a spinner to notify the user the app is working on something
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80))
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
        activityIndicator.backgroundColor = (UIColor(white: 0.3, alpha: 0.5)) //creates a background behind the spinner
        activityIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

The code goes on to several if statements based on the login credentials and returning data from the server. Finally, is stops ignoring interaction events. Finally, I put this same code into an IBAction for a button I created to test the code. It works for the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine or rather I would say it works, as mention is because the process takes milliseconds and **not persives**, I recommend that you put **breakpoints** in your code so that when you press Build can view the interaction to steps in your code.

Comment: Thank you. Let me start by saying this is my fist app so I am learning everything. I put the breakpoint in and after I build, I tap the login button. I am then taken back to Xcode and the lower left of the window is full of stuff. Can you help me figure out what that is or point me to a reference? I don't really know how to even ask a questions as it is all unfamiliar to me (except my variables).

Comment: Congratulations on you, you must first identify the bottom where display space by varying its content and process outcome, then is identified in blue indicator is active breakpoints, even right side of this you may observe several arrows which you may be interested only in the first instance `Step into` which will allow you to continue in the **Debug** from your application until it stops by another breakpoint.

Comment: I suggest placing a breakpoint to met the condition validated user data and another before I change the action that removes the `activityIndicator` any further questions more explicitly ask him to create another question.